# Overflow defeats negative margin to hide border

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am designing a simple tab bar with a content panel.

To hide the bottom border for the current active tab, I use a negative `margin-bottom` and a `border-bottom` to hide the border for that tab.

[image: test1]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#wrapper {

}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px -1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

li.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Tab 1 (active)</li>
      <li>Tab 2</li>
      <li>Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
      My content
    </div>
</div>
```

It works perfect.

---

The problem comes when I want to add more tabs, so it overflows the container. The solution that comes to my mind is using `overflow-x: auto;`. The problem is that this also adds a vertical scrollbar, and I am not sure why. I could overcome this by using `overflow-y: hidden;`. But the real problem is that it makes impossible to "delete" the black bottom border of the current active tab anymore.

[image: test2]

You can run the snipped below, also you can uncomment the commented html li elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#wrapper {

}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px -1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Tab 1 (active)</li>
      <li>Tab 2</li>
      <li>Tab 3</li>
      <li>Tab 4</li>
      <li>Tab 5</li>
      <li>Tab 6</li>
      <li>Tab 7</li>
      <!--<li>Tab 8</li>
      <li>Tab 9</li>
      <li>Tab 10</li>-->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
      My content
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: test2bis]

Does anyone has a solution? If not, what would be an alternate way to accomplish this?

What I really want is to keep hiding the bottom border of the active tab, and also have the possibility of showing an horizontal scroll bar when there is horizontal overflow.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Let me edit and fix it. Edit: I have added Stack Snippets and removed links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To hide the bottom border for the current active tab, I use a negative
> `margin-bottom` and a `border-bottom` to hide the border for that tab.

Instead, you can use `box-shadow: 0 -1px black inset;` for `<ul>` and `box-shadow: 1px -1px lightgray inset;` for `li.active`.

Once you have done all of this, you don't need negative `margin-bottom` anymore.

> The problem is that this also adds a vertical scrollbar, and I am not
> sure why. I could overcome this by using `overflow-y: hidden;`.

It adds a vertical scrollbar to `ul` because you added `margin-bottom: -1px;` to it's child (`li`) and it overflows Y axis.

I don't know how to fix horizontal scrollbar but i think you can fix it with a javascript carousel like owlcarousel, slick carousel etc.

Here is the example working:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#wrapper {

}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid black; */
  box-shadow: 0 -1px black inset;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0; /* you don't need to use bottom margin anymore. */
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li.active {
  /* border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray; */
  box-shadow: 1px -1px lightgray inset;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Tab 1 (active)</li>
      <li>Tab 2</li>
      <li>Tab 3</li>
      <li>Tab 4</li>
      <li>Tab 5</li>
      <li>Tab 6</li>
      <li>Tab 7</li>
      <!--<li>Tab 8</li>
      <li>Tab 9</li>
      <li>Tab 10</li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    My content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "delete" the black bottom border of the current active tab

You can use `border-bottom-color: transparent`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#wrapper {

}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

li.active {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li class="active">Tab 1 (active)</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<div>
<div id="content">
  My content
</div>
</div>
```

> showing an horizontal scroll bar when there is horizontal overflow

I think you forgot to close one of your divs, and your content was inside .wrapper! So just fix that up, and stick on `overflow: auto` and a max width to make sure it doesn't expand.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

li.active {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li class="active">Tab 1 (active)</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  My content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately making the border transparent hides it, I already thought about this solution but it was not suitable. Please have a look at Soner Mutlu's answer. I have tried it and works for my use-case.